# Python: Improvement (Code reduction): Compact write json to FTP

Tags: python, json, file, file-upload, converters

This is my current code:

```
def ftp_upload(local_ftpfile_path, ftp_ftpfile_path):
    json_data = {...}
    with open(local_ftpfile_path, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(json_data, f)
    f.close()
    file = open(local_ftpfile_path, 'rb')  # file to send
    try:
        session.storbinary('STOR ' + ftp_ftpfile_path, file)  # send the file
    except ... :
        ...
    else:
        ...
```

Everything works, but I think it's a little stupid to open two files.

How can I convert it to just one file, so either just to `f` or to `file`, but not both.

How would you have to change the `w` and the `rb`?

Thanks for the help!

best regards,

Lukas

Comment: Code that works and needs improvement is kindof OT here. Try https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Try using an `io.BytesIO` instance instead of an actual file.